# xpath query for image url

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, image, xpath

I am writing an app for my school newspaper, which is run completely online through wordpress. I am using Hpple to parse the html. From the following:

```
</div>
            <div id="fs-2" class="fs">
                <div id="fsh-2" class="fsh">
            <div id="fdh-2" class="fdh"><a href="http://www.mabearnews.com/entertainment/2012/12/26/hit-or-mis-les-miserables-review/">Hit or &#8216;Mis&#8217;: Les Miserables Review<br> by *******</a></div>
            <a href="http://www.mabearnews.com/entertainment/2012/12/26/hit-or-mis-les-miserables-review/"><img src="http://www.mabearnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/les-miserables-2012-wallpapers-les-miserables-2012-movie-32697313-1280-800-600x375.jpg" id="fph-2" class="fph" /></a>
```

What xpath query string would return the image url (img src)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html content is not well-formed.

Assuming this is the proper html content:

```
<div id="fs-2" class="fs">
    <div id="fsh-2" class="fsh">
        <div id="fdh-2" class="fdh"><a href="http://www.mabearnews.com/entertainment/2012/12/26/hit-or-mis-les-miserables-review/">Hit or &#8216;Mis&#8217;: Les Miserables Review<br> by *******</a></div>
        <a href="http://www.mabearnews.com/entertainment/2012/12/26/hit-or-mis-les-miserables-review/"><img src="http://www.mabearnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/les-miserables-2012-wallpapers-les-miserables-2012-movie-32697313-1280-800-600x375.jpg" id="fph-2" class="fph" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can get the image URL with this xpath query:

```
//div[@id="fsh-2"]/a/img/@src
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm having some other problems as well but I'll try to sort those out myself first before asking another question straight off the bat.